# Section own objects by touch in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch, interaction

I've got a few planes on my OpenGlSurfaceView. Now I want to detect whether a plane is touched. I found a few topics on stackoverflow and in other forums, but I don't know how to deal with them. Maybe anyone could help me.

My planes are all of that structure:

```
public SimplePlane() {
        float textureCoordinates[] = { 
                0.0f, 1.0f, //
                1.0f, 1.0f, //
                0.0f, 0.0f, //
                1.0f, 0.0f, //
        };

        short[] indices = new short[] { 
                0, 1, 
                2, 1, 
                3, 2 };

        float[] vertices = new float[] { 
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

        setIndices(indices);
        setVertices(vertices);
        setTextureCoordinates(textureCoordinates);
    }
```

I've got an own class for all my Meshes, so SimplePlane extends Mesh. Here you can see the draw method in the Mesh class:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
        gl.glColor4f(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
        if (colorBuffer != null) {
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
        }

        if (mShouldLoadTexture) {
            loadGLTexture(gl);
            mShouldLoadTexture = false;
        }
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null) {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        }


        gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, numOfIndices,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null) {
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }
```

And that the onDrawFrame Method of my Renderer:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(_red, _green, _blue, 0.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0,0,0,    0,0,0,   0,0,0);        

        gl.glLoadIdentity();    
        gl.glRotatef(_ry, 0f, 1f, 0f);

        root.draw(gl);  // a group of meshes    

    }
```

But now I don't know how I can start to detect a touch of my plane. I read much about color picking or ray picking, but I don't know where I should start in my code to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

First get the point where the user touched on screen using `myGLSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener())` (where myOnTouchListener implements [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)).

Then you need to get the MatrixGrabber, MatrixStack, MatrixTracking classes from the API demo's (C:\android-sdk\samples\android-7\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\spritetext).

Next, to use the MatrixGrabber, first attach it as a wrapper to your GLSurfaceView:

```
public class GraphicsEngine extends Activity {
protected GLSurfaceView mGLView;
protected GraphicsRenderer graphicsRenderer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.graphics);

        graphicsRenderer = new GraphicsRenderer(this);

        mGLView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.graphics_glsurfaceview1);

        // ------
        // THIS BIT HERE
        mGLView.setGLWrapper(new GLSurfaceView.GLWrapper() {
        public GL wrap(GL gl) {
            return new MatrixTrackingGL(gl);
        }});
        // ------


        mGLView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);         
        mGLView.setRenderer(graphicsRenderer);

}
```

Then you can get the matrices needed for [GLU.gluUnProject()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluUnProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29). This last method gives you a 3D point on the near-plane (i.e. z = near-plane) where the user touched. You can create a ray using it and the camera 'eye' point, and then detect which objects in your 3D world the ray intersected to get which objects the user picked*:

```
    MatrixGrabber matrixGrabber = new MatrixGrabber();
    matrixGrabber.getCurrentModelView(gl);  
    matrixGrabber.getCurrentProjection(gl);

    float[] vector = new float[4]; 

    // x and y come from the x/y you get from the OnTouchListener. 
    // OpenGL works from the bottom left corner, so flip the y
    GLU.gluUnProject(x, mGLView.getHeight()-y, 0.9f, matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0, matrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, new int[]{mGLView.getTop(),mGLView.getLeft(),mGLView.getWidth(),mGLView.getHeight()}, 0, vector, 0);

    Vector3f pickPosition = new Vector3f();
            if(vector[3]!=0){
                pickPosition.x = vector[0] / vector[3];
                pickPosition.y = vector[1] / vector[3];
                pickPosition.z = vector[2] / vector[3];
            }
```

*This last code snippet I'm not 100% certain works, but the real solution will look something like it

Edit: updated the last code snippet

Comment: Okay now I get a position. But at the moment I'm not sure wheater that is the right position. I think it looks well.. But how should I check wheter that pickPosition is inside my plane?

Comment: Change x and y in gluUnproject to be `x = mGLView.getWidth() / 2` and `y = mGLView.getHeight() / 2` i.e. the middle of the screen. This should produce the vector (0,0,1) = perpendicular to the plane of the screen / near plane. Set x to be where the user clicks but keep y as the screen center and you should get a bunch of vectors on the x/z plane. Also you can draw the rays onto your screen using `gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, etc)`. If you see the lines just as a dot or nothing until you start rotating around, then you are looking straight along the line and the picking is working

Comment: also I assume your game is 2D?

If so, you can cheat by using `GLU.gluProject`[1]. You use it to find the x and y screen coordinates of each of the four vertices of your planes. You can then just work out whether the user clicked somewhere inside that box (using the values you get from OnTouchListener).

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluProject%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int%29

Comment: No no I don't develope a game. It's more a kind of a compass. I'm experimenting at the moment. But I use 3D, because im at the [0,0,0] Point and rotating my coordinate system with the Orientation Sensor. So I get the direction of my compass. Know I want to test wheter it works to show some informations when I touch on my informations.. But I don't understand why you mean with your post 11 minutes ago. Can you describe it more? Also I think that my pick vector is not correct.. Is that correct for a line: float[] vertices = new float[] { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, x, y, z} ?

Comment: What I meant about GLU.Project is basically doing the reverse of unproject. Unproject takes where the user clicks on the screen and converts it into 3D coordinates. Project takes your 3D objects and turns them into (2D) screen coordinates.

Comment: Mmh okay I understand. But how should I check whether I've got coordinates which are insinde an object? I'm not sure how this will work..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6036/discussion-between-spoon-thumb-and-prengepower)